# Is there an explicit type constructor for (->) in Coq?

Tags: types, coq, partial-application

I'm trying to define a class that provides identity and composition.  Besides other useful instances (List with nil and concatenation; Relations with, well, identity and composition ;-) ), I'd like to have an instance for functions.

Given

```
Class Cat (C0 : Type) (C1 : C0 -> C0 -> Type) :=
  {   identity : forall a, C1 a a
  ;   compose : forall {a b c : C0}, C1 b c -> C1 a b -> C1 a c
  (*  snip: some laws  *)
  }.
```

I'd like to be able to define something like

```
Instance Cat (->) := { ... }.
```

but operators in Coq don't work like that.  First I assumed `->` is a Notation, but `Locate "_ -> _".` claimed this was an `Unknown notation`.  Using `fun a b => a -> b` kinda works, but the types look funny afterwards.

```
> Check (identity nat).
identity nat
     : (fun a b : Type => a -> b) nat nat
```

(Same goes for `Eval compute in`, seems it does not simplify types.)  I'd prefer the more readable `identity nat : nat -> nat`.  (At present, the types become unreadable for the stuff I'm doing.)

Is there any way to get the 'raw' `->` or at least convince Coq to give me nicer types?

---

Side note:  I'm building a lot of `Inductive`s representing evaluation semantics, my goal is to map subsets of 'normal' programming languages onto Coq and back, transfer security constraints and do magic.  I'm forced to prove the same things over and over again with different constructors and hope this will allow me to prove stuff once and only once.  I believe categories are the right way of abstracting this.  I'm including this note here in case I'm wrong, maybe there is a better way of doing this that sidesteps the whole `->` issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer part of the question. `->` is not a notation like `+` and `exists` and `{ ... | ... }`, it's built into the parser, like `forall`. The syntax `a -> b` is equivalent to `forall x:a, b` when `x` is not free in `b` (I don't know if it's equivalent in all circumstances, there may be uses where `x` cannot occur in `b` and you have to use `->`).

The reason is that function abstraction and application, and perforce their types, are fundamental in Coq, they aren't derived from more primitive notions. You cannot directly muck with `fun`, application, `->` or `forall`, because they aren't first-class objects.

That being said, type classes are a way to muck around with application specifically. I'm not familiar with them, so I don't know if there's a way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, [Logic.v](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/theories/Init/Logic.v?view=markup&revision=15929&root=coq) defines "Notation "A -> B" := (forall (_ : A), B) : type_scope."